# ClassLoader.getSystemResource() does not work in OSGI Bundle

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, osgi-bundle

I had an existing jar, which I have converted to OSGI Bundle now.

Problem is that now (as OSGI Bundle), it can not load resources. 
I am using `ClassLoader.getSystemResource()` method, it returns `null`.

Used code:

```
java.net.URL jdbc = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/company/cfg/provider/JDBC.xml");
```

I do not have access to source code so please tell some way by changing configuration (manifest file or something else) to make it work.

Bundle.getResource() works but I can not change the source code.

Comment: There is no such way. `getSystemResource()` does what the name suggests. That’s why it’s name is not `getResourceFromAMagicallyDeterminedClassLoader()`

Comment: @Holger  : I am not expert in OSGI. getSystemResource() works in non - osgi applications.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OSGi. `getSystemResource()` works [as its documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource-java.lang.String-) for resources accessible via the system class loader (which is the one loading ordinary standalone applications). It doesn’t work for other class loaders. The whole point of OSGi is to have *bundles* instead of one global application class loader. So if you have code relying on `getSystemResource()`, it isn’t compatible with OSGi. Or any other non-trivial application structure.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is that an OSGi bundle uses it's own ClassLoaders. So what you want to do is get a hold of the OSGi ClassLoader:

```
    java.net.URL jdbc = getClass().getClassLoader()
                                  .getResource("com/company/cfg/provider/JDBC.xml");
```

Or in the case the call happens in a static context with in the class `MyClass`:

```
java.net.URL jdbc = MyClass.class.getClassLoader()
                              .getResource("com/company/cfg/provider/JDBC.xml");
```

The difference between calling the static `ClassLoader` and `getClass().getClassLoader()`, is that in the first case you get an instance of `java.lang.ClassLoader` which cannot handle OSGi bundles properly, and the second call will get a `ClassLoader` that was used to load the current class which is part of an OSGi bundle.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. Calling a `static` method via an instance doesn’t change the invocation in any way.

Comment: @Holger you are right, I added an example for that case as well.

Comment: For what case? `getSystemResource` is a `static` method. Whatever you prepend to the invocation is irrelevant, the result is still the same as calling `ClassLoader.getSystemResource` as in the question.

Comment: However when using `getResource` instead of `getSystemResource` that should make a difference.

Comment: Right, the questioner already wrote that `getResource()` works but (s)he can not change the code.

Comment: So does it mean that without changing source code, I can not solve this problem?  Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Yes. Without changing the source code (actually *fixing* the source code, because it is clearly broken) you cannot solve this problem.